# Awk: generating icalendar file. How to print some consecutive lines?

Tags: awk, icalendar

> Thanks to Ed Morton's answer, I could do some testing with Thunderbird and icalendar validator. I edited my question adding entries without description and the expected result with precise requirements.

I'm writing a script to generate an icalendar file from a planing text file. I'd like to get the description content with the lines coming after the date. Say I've got a planning file:

```
lun 06 05 2019 08 15 09 00 F206
    A descritpion text.
ven 10 05 2019 11 00 11 45 G202
    Another description text
    - on multiple; 
    - lines.
lun 13 05 2019 08 15 09 00 F206
ven 17 05 2019 11 00 11 45 G202
    A long description with more than 75 characters.
    This happen often when multiple lines are
    joined in one. So the program shoud split every lines
    To 75 characters including the word description.
lun 20 05 2019 08 15 09 00 F206
    A description text.
```

My script looks like this, I'm a newbie with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk ' BEGIN { print "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n\
... some entries here ...\r\n\
END:VTIMEZONE\r" ;}
$1~/^(lun|mar|mer|jeu|ven)$/ { print "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n\
... some entries here ...\r\n\
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:"$4""$3""$2"T"$5""$6"00\r\n\
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:"$4""$3""$2"T"$7""$8"00\r\n\
TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n\
DESCRIPTION: >>>HERE I NEED THE DESCRIPTIVE LINES<<<< \r\n\
END:VEVENT\r"}
END { print "END:VCALENDAR" } ' < $1 > $1.ics
```

expected result:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T090000
DESCRIPTION:A descritpion text.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T114500
DESCRIPTION:Another description text\n- on multiple;\n- lines.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T090000
END:VEVENT                  
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T114500
DESCRIPTION:A long description with more than 75 characters.\nThis happen
 often when multiple lines are\njoined in one. So the program shoud split 
 every lines\nTo 75 characters including the word description.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190520T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190520T090000
DESCRIPTION: A description text.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

So the exact requirements are:

1. Lines without description should not print DESCRIPTION:.
2. Multiline description should be joined an separated with a literal \n. This is working with a `printf "%s%s", $0, "\\n"`
3. The lines should be splited to fewer than 75 characters, ending with a \r\n
4. The additional description lines should begin with a space.

Comment: I see you've looked up and added the complete specifications: well done!

Comment: In case case someone is interested, [here](https://gitlab.com/ppochon/scripts/tree/master/calendrify) is the final code. One script, `qcal`questions the user, creating one markdown file for each classe containing every lesson and a general icalendar file. The second, `ucal` update the .ics from the descriptions in the .md files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    ORS="\r\n"

    print "BEGIN:VCALENDAR"
    print "... some entries here ..."
    print "END:VTIMEZONE"
}
/^[^[:space:]]/ {
    prtEndVevent()

    print "BEGIN:VEVENT"
    print "... some entries here ..."

    date = $4 $3 $2
    begt = $5 $6 "00"
    endt = $7 $8 "00"

    print "DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:" date "T" begt
    print "DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:"   date "T" endt
    next
}
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    desc = (desc == "" ? "DESCRIPTION:" : desc RS) $0
}
END {
    prtEndVevent()
    print "END:VCALENDAR"
}

function prtEndVevent(       wid) {
    if ( desc != "" ) {
        wid = 74
        gsub(RS,"\\n",desc)
        while ( desc !~ /^ ?$/ ) {
            print substr(desc,1,wid)
            desc = " " substr(desc,wid+1)
        }
        desc = ""
    }
    if ( endVevent != "" ) {
        print endVevent
    }
    endVevent = "END:VEVENT"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
... some entries here ...
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T090000
DESCRIPTION:A descritpion text.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T114500
DESCRIPTION:Another description text\n- on multiple;\n- lines.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T090000
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T114500
DESCRIPTION:A long description with more than 75 characters.\nThis happen
 often when multiple lines are\njoined in one. So the program shoud split
 every lines\nTo 75 characters including the word description.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190520T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190520T090000
DESCRIPTION:A description text.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Note that this is wrapping at character positions, not word boundaries, so if a word crosses the 75th char position it will be split. If that's not desirable you can update `prtDesc()` to print one word at a time, checking if the total length of all words + blanks printed plus the next word would be less than 75 (and decide how to handle a description string that is 75+ chars long with no spaces!) or call the UNIX command `fold` to do the wrapping for you.

If you're ever considering using `getline` make sure to read and completely understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.

Comment: Thunderbird reads the file perfectly an icalendar.org validator returns "Success! No errors found." Thx for your patience, I'm studiying your code to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You really are on the right track. Here's your script integrated with the `flag` logic:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {print "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n\
... some entries here ...\r\n\
END:VTIMEZONE\r" ;}
$1~/^(lun|mar|mer|jeu|ven)$/ && flag {flag = !flag; print "END:VEVENT\r"}
$1~/^(lun|mar|mer|jeu|ven)$/ && !flag {flag = !flag; print "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n\
... some entries here ...\r\n\
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:"$4""$3""$2"T"$5""$6"00\r\n\
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:"$4""$3""$2"T"$7""$8"00\r\n\
TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n\
DESCRIPTION: "; next}
flag {print $0}
END { print "END:VCALENDAR" } ' < $1
```

Output:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
... some entries here ...
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190506T090000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DESCRIPTION:
    Some descriptive lines here.
    Lorem ipsumi dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitr.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190510T114500
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DESCRIPTION:
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
    - enim
    - ad minim veniam.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T081500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190513T090000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DESCRIPTION:
    exercitation ullamco
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
... some entries here ...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20190517T114500
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DESCRIPTION:
    quis nostrud
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: It's working well with the flag. The only problem being I need the description on the same line. I'm trying with Ed Morton answer now, because I can read it better than my own code.

Comment: @omisson I never intended to (re-write) the script for you: I was just showing you how to take one step further based on your posted code and idea.